# wget download all images loaded by a PHP from a custom website

Tags: php, linux, macos, operating-system, wget

I have following problem:

I want to download all pictures on a webpage with wget. Normally I can to this with

```
wget -nd -r -P ./ -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png somepage.com
```

But the problem is, that the pictures on my webpage are loaded from a `PHP` Script so wget cant download them. The `PHP` seems to work like every pic has it own ID and the script (called `file.php`) gets the ID (`file.php?id=someID`) and redirects to a

> /files/.jpg

Any Ideas how to solve this?

-- dunklesToast

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use --page-requisites (-p for short) instead of -r here as it downloads everything the page needs to display but no other pages, and I don't have to think about what kind of files I want.

Actually I'm usually using something like

```
wget -E -H -k -p http://textbook.s-anand.net/ncert/class-xii/chemistry/hello-this-first-chapter
```

This means:

-E: Append .html to the file name if it is an HTML file but doesn't end in .html or similar
-H: Download files from other hosts, too
-k: After downloading convert any link in it so they point to the downloaded files
-p: Download anything the page needs for proper offline viewing
Or you can try some thing like

```
wget -p www.example.com/index.html
```

However, I guess it will not be able to do some clever things (involving javascript). It depends on your page.